# Java regex expression trouble in split function call

Tags: java, regex, string, split, regex-greedy

I am having some trouble with creating a regular expression in java, where I want it to match all parts of a string that have a single `;` and none are a `;;` in the string.

Such as in the string `today;i;;drank water` the `;` after today would be a match and the `;;` would not be a match. So far I have tried the regex `;{1}` to say match if one and only one `;`.

However it keeps matching the double `;;`. Same goes for the regex `;{1,2}` which says match one `;` but not two or more `;`. Both regex are of the **greedy** kind. Also I am using the regex with the `String.split(regular expression)` java function.

Can anyone help with what may be going wrong or if my understanding of regular expression formation is a little off for why my regex are not working correctly?

Also as of note the output I get from the split is as such for the `today;i;;drank water`

```
today
i

drank water
```

Yes the 3rd element if a blank in the split array string.

Comment: Do you know that formatting the text reduces the trouble?

Comment: And you don't want to match ;d  in the second part?

Comment: I don't know if it's legal expression, but you could try ;{1,1}

Comment: @Suspended gets the same output but it was worth the try

Comment: @Suspended: it is, but it is useless too (it is the same than `;{1}` of simply `;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following expression: `\b;\b`. An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/eG1eZ9/1).

```
String str = "today;i;;drank water";
        String[] split = str.split("\\b;\\b");
        for(String s : split)
            System.out.println(s);
```

Yields:

```
today
i;;drank water
```

Comment: that did the trick! thanks for the help i know simple regular expressions but am not a master so sometimes these types give me trouble since i don't have to use them too often!

Comment: @jgr208: You usually get the hang of them when a couple of them explode in your face :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use a negative lookahead/lookbehind:

```
(?<!;);(?!;)
```

This means: a semicolon not preceeded and not followed by a semicolon.

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/cB7oJ7/1